# Help with reading data from ADXL373 Accelerometer (I2C)

Tags: sensors, accelerometer

I am using [ADXL373Z](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Analog-Devices/EVAL-ADXL373Z?qs=QNEnbhJQKva6ENie%252BWXLsQ%3D%3D) accelerometer with Arduino Uno for a project.

When I run the code, I am getting incorrect values which are probably not even acceleration data. I am thinking it might be a wiring problem, I attached circuit diagram below. This is my first Arduino project, and I couldn't find any other applications with the sensor I am using so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Datasheet for sensor : https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adxl373.pdf

Code ( for x-axis data only) :

```
// ADXL373 Accelerometer Test

#include <Wire.h>

/* -------- REGISTERS -------- */
#define ADDRESS_ADXL373 0x53 // sensor adress (assumes MISO pin high)
#define ADDRESS_POWER_CTL 0x3F // power control
#define ADDRESS_MEASURE 0x0E // measurement control
#define ADDRESS_TIMING 0x3D // output data rate and extarnal timing triggers
#define ADDRESS_XDATA_H 0x08 // x-axis acceleration data [11:4]
#define ADDRESS_XDATA_L 0x09 // x-axis acceleration data [3:0]
#define ADDRESS_YDATA_H 0x0A // y-axis acceleration data [11:4]
#define ADDRESS_YDATA_L 0x0B // y-axis acceleration data [3:0]
#define ADDRESS_ZDATA_H 0x0C // z-axis acceleration data [11:4]
#define ADDRESS_ZDATA_L 0x0D // z-axis acceleration data [3:0]
/* -------- REGISTERS -------- */

#define SCALE_FACTOR 0.2f // 200 mg per LSB scaling factor
#define GRAVITY_EARTH 9.80665f // gravity of earth in m/s^2

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while(!Serial);
  Serial.println("ADXL373 Accelerometer Test");
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADDRESS_ADXL373);
  Wire.write(ADDRESS_POWER_CTL);
  Wire.write(0x03); // activate full bandwith measurement mode
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  delay(50);
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADDRESS_ADXL373);
  Wire.write(ADDRESS_MEASURE);
  Wire.write(0x04); // set output signal bandwith to 2560 Hz
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  delay(50);
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADDRESS_ADXL373);
  Wire.write(ADDRESS_TIMING);
  Wire.write(0x80); // set output data rate to 5120 Hz
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  delay(50);
}

void loop() {
  byte xAxisH, xAxisL;
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADDRESS_ADXL373);
  Wire.write(ADDRESS_XDATA_H);
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(ADDRESS_ADXL373, 1, true);
  xAxisH = Wire.read();
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADDRESS_ADXL373);
  Wire.write(ADDRESS_XDATA_L);
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(ADDRESS_ADXL373, 1, true);
  xAxisL = Wire.read();
  int16_t xAxisFinal;
  xAxisFinal = (uint16_t) xAxisH << 8 | xAxisL; // bit shift and combine two components
  xAxisFinal = xAxisFinal >> 4; // 12-bit resolution
  float xAccel;
  xAccel = xAxisFinal * SCALE_FACTOR * GRAVITY_EARTH;
  Serial.print("Xa = "); Serial.println(xAccel);
  delay(200);
}
```

Circuit Diagram :

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Results from Serial Monitor (in m/s^2) :

[image: Serial Monitor]

Comment: `xAxisFinal = xAxisH << 4 | xAxisL;` I think you mean `<< 8`.

Answer (score 5):

According to the datasheet, the 12 bits of the X acceleration are stored
into the registers `XDATA_H` and `XDATA_L` as follows:

```
XDATA_H:   b₁₁b₁₀b₉ b₈ b₇ b₆ b₅ b₄
XDATA_L:   b₃ b₂ b₁ b₀ x  x  x  x
```

where `x` means “reserved”.

Now, there are two issues with this code:

```cpp
xAxisFinal = xAxisH << 4 | xAxisL; // bit shift 12-bit output data
```

The first issue is that, by shifting `xAxisH` by four places, the bits
b₇–b₄ end up in the same positions as the bits b₃–b₀ in `xAxisL`. Then,
when those values are combined with `|`, the bit b₇ gets mixed with b₃,
b₆ with b₂, etc. If you really want to shift `xAxisH` left by four
places, you should also shift `xAxisL` right by four places.

The second issue is that the x data is a signed number represented as
two's complement, and the sign bit (b₁₁) ends up in the wrong place. For
example, if the measured value is −16 (XDATA_H:XDATA_L = 0xff:0x00),
you end up reading 4980 (0x0ff0). In order to avoid this issue you could
[sign extend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) the 12-bit number to 16 bits.

I would suggest, though, a completely different approach. The number is
left justified in the sensor registers, so just keep it like this:

```cpp
xAxisFinal = (uint16_t) xAxisH << 8 | xAxisL;
```

The intermediate cast to `uint16_t` is here to avoid an undefined
behavior, the final result is signed. If there is some risk that the
reserved bits are non-zero (the datasheet is not very clear in this
respect), you could

```cpp
xAxisFinal &= 0xfff0;  // clear last 4 bits
```

Note that now the unit of the acceleration is 1/16 of the resolution of
the sensor, and all values you get are multiples of 16. I don't expect
this to be an issue. If you really want to use the sensor resolution as
your unit, you could now shift `xAxisFinal` four places to the right,
which would automatically perform the sign extension.

---

**Edit**: Addressing the edited code from the OP:

> I modified the code according to your suggestions. But I am still
> getting incorrect values from serial monitor.

What I see in your post is very small values, around ±3 LSBs of the
sensor. This could very well be sensor noise. But then, there is the
occasional larger value. Interestingly, those larger values seem to be
very close to ±16 LSBs, hinting at some kind of communication
problem.

I guess the answer is in this warning from the sensor's datasheet:

> Always read acceleration data using multibyte transfers to ensure that
> a concurrent and complete set of x, y, and z acceleration data is
> read.

Imagine the sensor is outputting only noise, and the noise fluctuates
between −1 and +1 LSB. What you expect then is:

```
value  XDATA_H   XDATA_L
  −1   11111111  11110000
  +1   00000000  00010000
```

If you read `XDATA_H` and `XDATA_L` in two different transactions, you
may well read 0b11111111 for `XDATA_H` (as the sensor is reading  −1),
then read `00010000` for `XDATA_L` (as it is getting +1). When you
combine these two readings together, you get

```
value  XDATA_H   XDATA_L
 −15   11111111  00010000
```

I suggest you follow the recommendation from the datasheet and read both
registers in one go:

```cpp
Wire.beginTransmission(ADDRESS_ADXL373);
Wire.write(ADDRESS_XDATA_H);
Wire.endTransmission(false);
Wire.requestFrom(ADDRESS_ADXL373, 2, true);
xAxisH = Wire.read();
xAxisL = Wire.read();
```

Comment: Heh. Your answer came in about when my comment did.

Comment: Thanks, I modified the code according to your suggestions. But I am still getting incorrect values from serial monitor. I edited the code and results in my post. If you have any other suggestions I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Maxxie: See expanded answer.